# Dealing with GMT+00:00 timezone between controller and VF page where JS Applies local timezone

Tags: apex, javascript, datetime, timezone

I am having a bit of difficulties with timezones here... I have a calendar app in JavaScript that automatically applies your current timezone to dates, but I have a Force.com guest user account in GMT+00:00, so when dealing with times in my controller, no timezone is added for adjustment.

It makes sense for the guest user to be in GMT+00:00 timezone so that any user, anywhere can access it...

I have been kind of struggling in finding a stable, consistent approach to send GMT+00:00 timezone times to my controller (when JS is applying local timezone...) and then get GMT+00:00 timezone times back from the controller to apply timezone offset to.

Any advice would be great!

Comment: Can you revert the values back to UTC in Javascript before submitting them to Salesforce? Seems like it would be the easiest place to reverse the change as you can determine the users timezone.